# sql server : how to get this result USING SQL SERVER QUERY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have `sql` table like:

```
 COL1   | COL2  
    A   | P  
    A   | Q  
    B   | P   
    B   | Q
```

I want a result like:

```
COL1 |COL2 
A    | P  
B    | Q
```

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried already? What, exactly, didn't work?

Comment: What is the logic for COL2?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
select COL1, 
    case 
       when COL1 = 'A' then MIN(COL2)
       when COL1 = 'B' then MAX(COL2)
    end
from @table
group by COL1
```

But the logic behind it is very limited to your sample result and wouldn't scale well. You need to provide more information. What is the logic behind getting the values for COL2?